# Horstmann C27 to Nest

Tags: thermostat, heating, nest

I'm in progress of changing Horstmann C27 with Nest Learning Thermostat Gen3. I'll share the images below, I'm looking for a way of mapping the cables to the Nest.

C27 supports both Hot Water and Central Heating through existing 3 cables (N, L, 3). In Nest, the Hot Water and Heating configurations are separate - so I can't wrap my mind around it. Also - I want to use Nest for both Central heating and Water.

Here's what I have done so far.

- N - In previous configuration - this was coming from somewhere in the wall. Mapped to N in Nest. Removed the external cable which used to be wired to a broken Netatmo power unit (seen in the image)
- L - In previous configuration - this was coming from somewhere in the wall. Mapped to L in Nest. Removed the external cable which used to be wired to a Netatmo power unit (seen in the image)
- 1 - In previous configuration, nothing is wired here.
- 2 - In previous configuration, nothing is wired here.
- 3 - In previous configuration, this is coming from somewhere in the wall. This is wired to 3 in Nest. (I assume this is incorrect, since heating isn't working now.)
- 4 - Removed the external cable which used to be wired to a broken Netatmo power unit (seen in the image)

Following some posts from diynot.com - I have 2, 5 and L (from the wall) combined into a choc-block going into L in the Nest; and the heating isn't working.

How do I wire this? Can't figure out why the Heating doesn't work.

### Old Configuration - picture includes the dead power line for Netatmo

Keep in mind - only N, L and 3 had wires coming from somewhere.
[image]

### New Configuration - help needed, heating doesn't work.

[image]